# Fill background color left to right CSS

Tags: css

Having a play around with some css3 today, transitions mainly.

What i would like to achieve is that upon hover of an li element the background will fill from left to right with a different colour, ideally i would like to be able to fill half way or all the way.. I have started a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/75Umu/)

Do i need to use the property

```
-vendor-prefix transition
```

Could anyone give me some pointers on achieving this please.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like this???
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/71/Dynamic-glide-navigation-with-jQuery-plugin

Comment: no, i would like the li element being hovered to fill from left to right with a different colour

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions This will tell you whether you need to use a vendor prefix or not. For webkit browsers you will need to use the webkit prefix.

Comment: I guess you want something like a gradient. If so, then this will help http://sapphion.com/2011/10/css3-gradient-transition-with-background-position/

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The thing you will need to do here is use a linear gradient as background and animate the background position. In code:

Use a linear gradient (50% red, 50% blue) and tell the browser that background is 2 times larger than the element's width (width:200%, height:100%), then tell it to position the background right.

```css
background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%) right;
background-size: 200% 100%;
```

On hover, change the background position to `left` and with `transition:all 2s ease;`, the position will change gradually (it's nicer with `linear` tough)

```css
background-position: left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/

As for the *-vendor-prefix*'es, see the comments to your question

*extra*:

If you wish to have a "transition" in the colour, you can make it 300% width and make the transition start at 34% (a bit more than 1/3) and end at 65% (a bit less than 2/3).

```css
background: linear-gradient(to left, red 34%, blue 65%) right;
background-size: 300% 100%;
```

#### Demo:

```css
div {
    font: 22px Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: red; /* default color */

    /* "to left" / "to right" - affects initial color */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, salmon 50%, lightblue 50%) right;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

Comment: +1 but I had to edit your fiddle to remove the -webkit-prefix in order to see it work in Firefox.  :-(

Comment: @Spudley You will need to use both as Webkit browsers do not currently use the stock transition.

Comment: @jezzipin - actually according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), Chrome doesn't require a prefix any more (although I guess Chrome isn't technically a webkit browser any more...). But my point was that the question specifically asked about prefixes, so the fact that the fiddle didn't work in all browsers due to the prefix was a bit of a faux-pas. :) Anyway, all sorted now.

Comment: @gar_onn how would i get the transition to stop at say 3/4 of the way? rather than filling up the element

Comment: You can use `background-position:75% bottom;` see [the backgound-position documentaion on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Comment: seriously @beardhatcode you should edit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size great answer!

Comment: Nice one, just two minor remarks/additions. 1) I noticed that in my case, I had to set the splits lightly beyond 50% in the normal case, and slightly below 50% in the hovered case to prevent left-over background. 2) If you apply 1, and then redefine the gradient for the hover-case, specify `background-image` rather than `background`, so `background-size` and `background-position`-properties aren't reset as well.

Answer (score 39):

A single css code on hover can do the trick:
`box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 #e0e0e0;`

A complete demo can be found in my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/shuvamallick/3o0h5oka/

Comment: Clever. I like it. I don't know about browser compatibility, but I like it.

Comment: The only thing I can see immediately is that the `100px` value needs to be hard-coded, so it's harder to use this as a class across multiple elements of varying widths.

Comment: It works, however box-shadow is a very expensive property to animate (in terms of system resources) https://csstriggers.com/box-shadow and also setting `transition: all;` is not the best. A similar effect could be achieved with pseudo elements: https://jsfiddle.net/f198x4bq/19/ . The same effect is achieved by transitioning the transform and opacity properties on `::before` and transition the color property on the button. And it addresses the problem that @armadadrive pointed out

Comment: This is easiest one and thats what exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

If you are like me and need to change color of text itself also while in the same time filling the background color check my solution.

Steps to create:

1. Have two text, one is static colored in color on hover, and the other one in default state color which you will be moving on hover
2. On hover move wrapper of the not static one text while in the same time move inner text of that wrapper to the opposite direction.
3. Make sure to add overflow hidden where needed

Good thing about this solution:

- Support IE9, uses only transform
- Button (or element you are applying animation) is fluid in width, so no fixed values are being used here

Not so good thing about this solution:

- A really messy markup, could be solved by using pseudo elements and att(data)?
- There is some small glitch in animation when having more then one button next to each other, maybe it could be easily solved but I didn't take much time to investigate yet.

Check the pen ---> https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/vpNoNq

```
<button class="btn btn--animation-from-right">
  <span class="btn__text-static">Cover left</span>
  <div class="btn__text-dynamic">
    <span class="btn__text-dynamic-inner">Cover left</span>
  </div>
</button>

.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;

  border: 2px solid #222;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: -1px;

  [class^="btn__text"] {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .btn__text-dynamic,
  .btn__text-dynamic-inner {    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 2;

    transition: all ease 0.5s;
  }

  .btn__text-dynamic {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #222;

    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &:hover {
    .btn__text-dynamic {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .btn__text-dynamic-inner {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
  }
}

.btn--animation-from-right {
    &:hover {
    .btn__text-dynamic {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .btn__text-dynamic-inner {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
  }
}
```

You can remove .btn--animation-from-right modifier if you want to animate to the left.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha np glad someone find it helpful .

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    font: 22px Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: red; /* default color */

    /* "to left" / "to right" - affects initial color */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, salmon 50%, lightblue 50%) right;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```