# Jquery sliding highlight

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I am using Jquery to highlight a span of text when a trigger is clicked.

I am looking for a way to have the text highlighted from left to right, instead of all in one go, to give a "real" feel - so that it looks like it's being highlighted by hand.

I can't find any documentation about this online.... Any ideas?

Here is the code:

(HTML)

```
The Law of Universal Gravitation is based on the observed fact 
that all masses attract all other masses. The force of 
<span id="to_highlight">attraction decreases as the distance 
between the masses increases.</span>
```

(JQuery)

```
if (count==4) {
  $('#to_highlight').css("background-color","#e8c5e8");
};
```

Comment: pls can you show me your code anywhere? I dont understand what is your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css) to accomplish what you are looking for.

Set a `background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 50%, white 50%);` and then use `background-position: left bottom;` or `background-position: right bottom;` combined with `transition:all 3s ease;` to get the left-to-right effect.

Here is a JSFiddle derived from gar_onn's answer (link on the first line):
http://jsfiddle.net/23zea/

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though this fiddle doesn't seem to work... Is it fine on your end?

Comment: @Julia: Works like a charm for me. I tested it on Mozilla Firefox 21.0 and Google Chrome 27.0. Ensure that you have javascript enabled, and then try again.

Comment: I found the problem, seems to not work on Safari.... Any way to fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: are you not getting the change in background color? or are you not getting just the left-to-right effect?

If the problem is just the left-to-right effect, you should add `-webkit-transition:all 3s ease;` to ensure support for transitions in Safari.

Comment: On safari I'm getting neither actually..! The text stays with a white background.

Comment: I'm at a loss, sorry. But try making a HTML file of your own with the code from the jsfiddle to check if the problem lies with jsfiddle.net or the code. That ought to help.

Comment: The jsfiddle works great when I open it in Chrome. I believe that safari doesn't support this linear-gradient. What a shame, because your solution is beautiful. Unfortunately i need it to work on all browsers :( I will try using @princejf 's solution

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this. JQuery animations depend on having an element to animate. Since I assume you probably don't want the text itself to be animated, you will have to animate a different element.

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeXSk/) with a method that you can call to animate the highlighting. It will make a new element on the fly that will be animated, then throw the element away and replace it with a class that will use css to highlight the element.

*HTML*

```
<button id="highlight_trigger">Highlight</button>
<span id="to_highlight">This text is what I want to highlight</span>
```

*JS*

```
$('#highlight_trigger').on('click', function() {
    var toHighlight = $('#to_highlight');
    if(toHighlight.hasClass('highlighted')) {
        highlightAnimation(toHighlight, false, 500);
    } else {
        highlightAnimation(toHighlight, true, 500);
    }
});

function highlightAnimation($elem, show, duration) {
    var startPos;
    var endPos;
    if(show) {
        startPos = '100%';
        endPos = '0%';
    } else {
        startPos = '0%';
        endPos = '100%';
        $elem.removeClass('highlighted');
    }
    var highlight = $('<div />').addClass('highlight_box').css('right', startPos);
    $elem.append(highlight);
    highlight.animate({right: endPos}, duration, function() {
        highlight.remove();
        if(show) {
            $elem.addClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
}
```

*CSS*

```
#to_highlight {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#to_highlight.highlighted, .highlight_box {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight_box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Depends on if you want to support browsers that don't have transition  or decent linear-gradient support. You raise a good point though.

Comment: Hey @princejef, thanks so much for your solution! It works great on jsfiddle, but when i copy/paste the code exactly into my work, the highlight happens all in one go, with no "slide"... Do you have a clue about what could have gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @Julia is the text being highlighted immediately or is it delayed by 500ms? And make sure you remove the background-color statement that you had before. It will override what I have written if they're both present

Comment: And @rktcool I think the other solution should work in Safari if you change linear-gradient to -webkit-linear-gradient with everything else the same. Linear gradient syntax is a mess right now. Check out [this page](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) for the full syntax breakdown. Sorry I would post this on your answer but I don't have the necessary rep yet.

Comment: @princejef it's delayed by 500ms

Comment: Alright I have a couple guesses. First, did you copy over the CSS too? The javascript depends on the CSS to properly display the animation. I suppose there could also be a problem with the `startPos` and `endPos` variables. Try hardcoding them as '100%' and '0%', respectively in the function just to see if that fixes it. Out of curiosity, what version of jQuery are you using?