# CSS Fill Box with rounded borders

Tags: html, css, fill

I have an example of an area that fills itself on hover, it is done by widening the `:before` pseudo-element from width 0 to width 100%. The problem I am getting is when the `:before` element is too narrow its borders won't match those of the parent element, this happens because the borders are rounded, and since circular borders' radii can't be bigger than the smallest of the object's dimensions this is understandable.

This creates a glitch at the beginning of the animation that I don't know how to fix.

I am also trying to find a way to fill the box with a diagonal line instead of the vertical line which is the right border of the pseudo-block, does anyone know a way to do this, ideally with only html and css?

Here's the code I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/tchikago/egtLx4re/2/

```
.fillingBox {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.fillingBox:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 15px;
    right: 100%;
    transition: right 2s;
}
.fillingBox:hover:before {
    right: 0;
}
```

For the following html element

```
<div class="fillingBox"></div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want it to start small and end big (width-wise)?

Comment: @Shahar, I was thinking of something like the image http://imgur.com/8sxUY6Q

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
.fillingBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, green 50%, red 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.fillingBox:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="fillingBox"></div>
```

This is a much better method, as it changes the background, which will always be the correct shape.

Comment: Thanks @imtheman this does exactly what I wanted and is more elegant than my solution, and also by using the angle property  of the gradient and a bigger background I can achieve the second effect that I wanted. Very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem can be done with CSS keyframe animations.
What I did was give the element a `min-width` of 30px, twice the border radius. This stops the corners from being deformed. Then the `:before` pseudo-element is hidden, and shown on hover. It is then offset 30px to the left with 0 opacity. Hovering causes the opacity to be set to 1 again and stretches the element.

```
.fillingBox:before {
    /* other stuff */
    display: none;
    min-width:30px;
    /* other stuff */
}
.fillingBox:hover:before {
    display: block;
    animation: redfill 600ms linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes redfill {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -30px;
        right: 100%;
    }
    1% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: 0px;
        right: 100%;
    }
    2% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0px;
        right: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left:0%;
        right: 0%;
    }
}
```

This has a little glitch where the initial animated width is 30px, but it is not very noticeable.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egtLx4re/4/)</kbd>