# CSS hover animation hides text

Tags: html, css, css-animations

if I toggle the hover effect, the background hides the text. Which atttribute shoud I add that the text of the listpoints is not under the ":before" background.

I also postet a codepen-link so it is easy for you to check my code.

Thanks

```
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>#1111111111</li>
      <li>#2222222222</li>
      <li>#3333333333</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  width: 100px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: green;
}

nav ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 0;

}

nav ul li:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBXwVB

Comment: The problem is the `:before` is hiding it.

Comment: z-index:-1 to :before, or different html/css...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpNdyO

Comment: @sinisake `z-index: -1` will not work right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, works if we set higher z-index to li it self, check codepen above... :)

Comment: @sinisake Ah... I answered in a different way. What do you think?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, better choice i would say...

Comment: z-index: -1 on :before and a higher z-index to li does not work.

Comment: @ChiefAlu Can you check my answer? Click on run snippet and also see the preview.

Comment: @ChiefAlu, it is working,, at least in FF and Chrome... check codepen link above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is, the overlay is coming on top of the text and hiding the contents below, since it is a white opaque background. Only way to use another `<span>` and set the `z-index` to a higher position than the overlay:

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  width: 100px;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  color: green;
}
nav ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><span>#1111111111</span></li>
    <li><span>#2222222222</span></li>
    <li><span>#3333333333</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: No need for the z-index, "position: relative" will suffice ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this effect using a `linear-background` and avoid using the `:before` selector, which seems to be a better approach.

For example

```
li {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position:left bottom;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover {
  background-position:right bottom,
}
```

As suggested by beardheadcode in this stack: [Fill background color left to right CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css)

There is although a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/