# Fill li item on hover in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate an `<li>` so that on hover it appears that there is a fill effect going from left to right.

This is what I have so far.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.hoverTest {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

.hoverTest li {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: #ff3232;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:left bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    background-position:right bottom;
}
.hoverTest li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
   <div class="hoverTest">
    <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Test Button</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I have a number of issues with this. First of all the fill effect is coming from right to left whereas I would like the opposite. No matter what I have tried with changing the positions of the backgrounds I just cannot get this to work.

Secondly, I would like there to be a small strip of the fill colour displayed to begin with as in this example by Jay Holtslander : https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/full/XmpMEp/

Finally the code I have at the moment seems to be relatively clunky, it is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css) in 2013 by beardhatcode. Is there a more modern, simpler way to implement this effect?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the advice, I was actually unaware that I could put a snippet in my question. Thanks to Suresh for doing this for me. Is there a guide somewhere on how to insert snippets of code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmp1dLuq/

Comment: @CBreeze: Frankly, the help around this really needs to be a lot better, but getting SE to do *anything* around snippets is an exercise in extreme patience/frustration.

Comment: @CBreeze: I've tried to fix that lack of documentation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `background-position` around and made the `red` background a bit larger than the blue one, which seems to have the desired effect.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.hoverTest {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

.hoverTest li {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: #ff3232;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 52%, blue 48%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    background-position:left bottom;
}
.hoverTest li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hoverTest">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Test Button</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Take a look at the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdLysrn2/1/

Comment: I'm not sure why you have been downvoted but for now this seems exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: People tend to downvote answers to get theirs up higher. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using box-shadow css property with inset value.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.hoverTest {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

.hoverTest li {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: blue;
    /* Old browsers */
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px red;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 140px 0px 0px red;
}
    
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    background-position:right bottom;
}
.hoverTest li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hoverTest">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Test Button</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will work :

```
.hoverTest li {
   background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 50%, red 50%);
   border-left:3px solid red;
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    background-position:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.hoverTest {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

.hoverTest li {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background: #ff3232;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverTest li:hover {
    background-position: left;
}
.hoverTest li a {
    color:white;
}






<div class="hoverTest">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test Button</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    background-color: red;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    transition: width 500ms ease;
}

li:hover:before {
   width: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test Button</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```