# Diagonally Transition Background Color on Hover From Bottom Left to Top Right

Tags: html, css, animation, transition, linear-gradients

I'm using the technique in the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css), except that I'm wondering if it's possible to slide a background color change from left to right *diagonally* - specifically, from bottom-left to top-right?

I have this `CSS` and `HTML` for a menu, for example:

```css
.menu {
background: #1481C3;
color: white;
border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}

.menu ul.links {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

.menu ul.links li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #0E99ED;
height: 64px;
line-height: 67px;
padding: 0 25px;
font-size: 15px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #0E99ED 50%, #1481C3 50%);
background-size: 200% 100%;
background-position: right bottom;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.menu ul.links li:hover {
background-position: left bottom;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="home">
          <div id="home" class="menu-icon-container">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="/images/home-icon.png" />
          </div>
          <span>Home</span>
        </li>
        <li class="assignments">
          <div class="menu-icon-container">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="/images/assignments-icon.png" />
          </div>
          <span>Assignments</span>
        </li>
        <li class="proctoring">
          <div class="menu-icon-container">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="/images/proctoring-icon.png" />
          </div>
          <span>Proctoring</span>
        </li>
        <li class="reports">
          <div class="menu-icon-container">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="/images/reports-icon.png" />
          </div>
          <span>Reports</span>
        </li>
        <li class="administration">
          <div class="menu-icon-container">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="/images/administration-icon.png" />
          </div>
          <span>Administration</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

And, to make it **horizontal**, I tried to change the styles of this class

```
.menu ul.links li {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0E99ED 50%, #1481C3 50%);
}
```

But that is not quite working as expected: [link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kwd0q3x6/9/)

I need the `li` to be 100% `#0E99ED` (light blue) initially and then 100% `#1481C3` (dark blue) on hover. Currently that ^ is initially taking up about 25% of the bottom left with `#0E99ED` and only about 75% of the total `li` on hover. It needs to be 0% initially and 100% on hover.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly all that is necessary is to increase the starting `background-size` so that no gradient is seen initially.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, lightblue 50%);
  background-size: 250% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: background-position .5s ease;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why `background-size` causes no gradient to be seen initially?

Comment: Because the actual image/gradient is much larger than the div "viewport" so the gradient is there you just can't see it starting. We're only seeing the right 40% say of it, until we move the "image" over to the right.