# How to make background color shift gradually into another color?

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I would like to make my website's background shift color halfway.

It should fade over to the other color. How could I do that?

The top of the website is green and halfway down it changes to blue, like this:

[image: website background color changes halfway down]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill background color left to right CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super easy, use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient), also add [`background-attachment:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) to make sure that the gradient isn't repeating.

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#d3ff6e, #00faff); /* customize colors here */
    background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

If you want to make the yellow color a bit more visible, add a percentage after the color like below:

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#d3ff6e 35%, #00faff); /* customize colors here */
    background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need as there is no picture attached.

But try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            animation: colorshift 5s infinite;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        @keyframes colorshift {
            0% {background: #eee;}
            50% {background: #000;}
            100% {background: #eee;}
        }

        h1 {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If this isn't what you need, please be more precise in formulating your question.

Comment: Sorry! I thought that I had attached a picture :/ Can you see the picture now?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background-position .5s;
  background-position: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.