# Hover effect transition out is breaking out of bounds of the border

Tags: css

I created a hover effect where the background changes from white to black from the bottom to the top over 150ms. Then after the hover the black transitions up but clips out of the border. Any CSS masters out there that can help me get a smooth transition out? Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Jack-Quinn/pen/mdoKGXx below is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="" class="bg-transition-hover-effect">
    Read More
  </a>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.bg-transition-hover-effect {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bg-transition-hover-effect:hover {
  color: white
}

.bg-transition-hover-effect::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  transition: transform 150ms;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg-transition-hover-effect:hover::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

I have tried different border radius sizes and it works without a border radius but I need it to be a pill shape. I have also tried to hide a black div behind the  tag and have it transition in > up then transition out > up but I ran into issues making that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` in `bg-transition-hover-effect` to hide it. But I recommend you refer to the better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212094/fill-background-color-left-to-right-css).

Comment: Thanks for the response, so I had overflow: hidden; previously and it wasn't working. I added it to the codpen and it worked. That being said when I added it to my project it didn't work and was confused because everything was the same, but the container. I realized for whatever reason the container needed display: flex; You can remove it in the codepen and see that it clips out of the border without it. I am not sure why this is.

Comment: As for the better way example you provided, I looked into it but that transition goes from right to left then back left to right. I would need it to go from right to left then back right to left. All that being said, adding flex to the container resolved my issue.

Comment: @Jack Quinn `transform` is not really used for this purpose, it should be used when the element allows overflow.